# Referring to external source in Flex compiler

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, compc

Is there a external-source-path option available in Flex compiler similar to external-library-path ?

My requirement is that, I am building a "SWC" file but I don't want to include certain folders inside my 'src' folder as these are anyway available in my other application during run time. (Trying to be resource constraint). So, I want to use these folders during compilation but do not want to include them in the generated "SWC" file.

-Ravi

Answer (score 0):

There is no "exclude" option, unfortunately, but it is not required that you include the main src folder - you can specify all the subfolders you actually want to include using `-include-sources`.

You could also use `-include-classes` or `-include-file` to specify individual files. Check out this [list of compiler options](http://www.docsultant.com/site2/articles/flex_cmd.html#compc_3_opt)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a external-source-path option available in Flex compiler
>   similar to external-library-path ?

Would Source-path work?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html

You can easily list multiple source paths.

> My requirement is that, I am building a "SWC" file but I don't want to
>   include certain folders inside my 'src' folder as these are anyway
>   available in my other application during run time. (Trying to be
>   resource constraint). So, I want to use these folders during
>   compilation but do not want to include them in the generated "SWC"
>   file.

If classes in your SWC have dependencies to other assets, they'll have to be compiled into the SWC.  How would the SWC know or not whether they'll be available, externally, at runtime or not?  If classes in a SWC have dependencies to other classes, those other classes will have to be compiled into the SWC for the same reason.

If identical classes are available to the SWF from multiple locations, then the final SWF (or SWC project) should optimize out the duplicates, resulting with only a single 'instance' of the entity in the final SWF.

Comment: How do I remove duplicate class files compiled into a SWF or SWC ?

Comment: Manually?  You don't!  The Flex Compiler will do that for you